# Texturing a uv map for complex mesh

Tags: uv

this is my mesh so far and its uv map, on the top is the stairs and the bottom is the walls
[image]

This is how big the texture is when i add it to the file and what i though would look nice is if i shrink it so that texture looks the same on every step but i dont want it to be repeated over and over [image]

what im trying to do is just copy and paste it so its on every step the same but the problem is the texture is too blurry and cant really see the details when its rendered, I looked everywhere and i can only find how to use the checkers texture or how to uv map, Any advice?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to pull this off using texture coordinate node combined with mapping node, and using project instead of UV. Or you might define your texture as a brush and texture paint it by hand.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i realized when exporting the texture you can select how big it is, made it bigger and it works much better but will have a look at your way

Answer (score 0):

### fOLLOW THE IMAGE GUIDE !

- Select Edges
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
- Select **EDGE DATA**
- Mark **SEAN**

Repeat in all you need make a **UV MAP**

- Select All
- Press <kbd>U</kbd>
- Select **UNWRAP**

Goto **UV IMAGE EDITOR**

- select the UVs you need to group
- Press CTRL + P ( *To pack Islands* )

**END**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### You can stack repeated UVs in groups to save space and scale the uv for better texture details

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not done yet, please give me a moment to continue, I have to change my workplace